# Whats the difference between call/1 and normal clause?

Tags: prolog, call

If I have :

```
 run(X) :- X.
```

What is the difference between :

```
... :- ..., call(Y).
```

and :

```
... :- ..., run(Y).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have:

```
run(X) :- X.
```

then you can see that it is *equivalent* to using `call/1` explicitly via

```
?- listing(run/1).
run(A) :-
        call(A).
```

From this, it follows that `call(X)` is also declaratively equivalent to `run(X)`. However, unless your Prolog compiler performs some kind of inlining, using`call/1` *directly* is almost certainly at least very, very slightly more efficient than calling `run/1` and have that invoke `call/1`.

As food for thought, think of cases like `run(!)`, and how in general using `!` in meta-calls could affect programs if `X` were *not* equivalent to `call(X)`.